# Do not un-highlight cell immediately after selection (instead, un-highlight it on view-will-appear)

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

I have a table view with custom cells that have **custom highlight styles** defined in delegate-functions `didHighlightRowAt` and `didUnhighlightRowAt` (e.g., I'm changing the background color).

However, when I select a cell, the unhighlighting function is triggered immediately - how can I avoid this? I want the cell to remain highlighted and instead, unhighlight it in viewwillappear.

Thanks!

[I set `tableView.selectionStyle` to `.none`, because it was the only way to do custom highlighting without using the standard selection style. might this be the problem?]

Comment: Do you maybe use `deselectRow(at:animated:)`, specifically in you `didSelectRow` method? That would trigger the unhighlight.

Comment: hmm, I only use it in `viewWillAppear`, so this can't be the problem

Comment: *"I'm changing the background color"* ... Are you *only* trying to change the  highlight background color? If so, it sounds like you are over-complicating the matter.

Comment: @DonMag I only change the color of a certain part of the cell, so not the whole background - thats why I did not use the standard selection style

Comment: Have you looked at overriding `setHighlighted()` and / or `setSelected()` in your custom cell?

Comment: ah, thanks! This seems to be the right approach! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've fixed this problem, however I think my solution is more like a work-around so better approaches are still highly appreciated!

It looks like the flow is the following:

```
- releasing a cell
- cell is unhighlighting
- cell becomes selected
```

So what I did was after unhighlighting, manually highlighting the cell again and then, in in viewWillAppear